# Проблема с удалением списка и еще какой-то баг (C++)

Tags: c++, структуры, двусвязный-список

Всем привет, завяз че-то. Может кто посмотрит? Задача: даны два двусвязных списка с элементами по возрастанию, нужно преобразовать их в третий с элементами по убыванию. 
Получить 3-ий список удалось. Проблема возникает при удалении структур (функция `deleteList`), вылетает ошибка

> .exe has triggered a breakpoint

. В ходе дебага выяснилось, что функция func каким-то образом меняет последовательность после `first1` и `first2`, не могу понять как. Может в этом проблема? Или я функцию `deleteList` неправильно написал?

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct list {
        int field;
        list *next, *prev;
    };

    list* init(int, list *&);
    list* add(list *, int);
    list* func(list *, list *, list *&);
    void show(list*);
    void deleteList(list *);

    int main() {
        int size, element, prevElement;
        list *list1, *list2,*list3;
        list *first1 = new list;
        list *first2 = new list;
        list *first3 = new list;
        cout << "Enter lists's size: ";
        cin >> size;
        cout << "Enter first list's elements (in increasing order)" << endl;
        cin >> element;
        list1=init(element, first1);
        prevElement = element;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            cin >> element;
            if (element < prevElement) {
                cout << "List's elements don't increase!" << endl;
                system("pause");
                return 1;
            }
            list1=add(list1, element);
        }

        cout << "Enter second list's elements (in increasing order)" << endl;
        cin >> element;
        list2=init(element, first2);
        prevElement = element;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            cin >> element;
            if (element < prevElement) {
                cout << "List's elements don't increase!" << endl;
                system("pause");
                return 1;
            }
            list2=add(list2, element);
        }

        list3 = func(list1, list2, first3);
        cout << endl << "Result:" << endl;
        show(first3);
        deleteList(first1);
        deleteList(first2);
        deleteList(list3);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    list* init(int x, list *&first) {
        list *temp = new list;
        temp->field = x;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        first = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    list* add(list *tail, int x) {
        list *temp = new list;
        list *p = tail->next;
        tail->next = temp;
        temp->field = x;
        temp->next = p;
        temp->prev = tail;
        return temp;
    }

    list* func(list *tail1, list *tail2, list *&first3) {
        list *list3;
        if ((tail1->field) > (tail2->field)) {
            list3 = init(tail1->field, first3);
            tail1 = tail1->prev;
        }
        else if ((tail1->field) < (tail2->field)) {
            list3 = init(tail2->field, first3);
            tail2 = tail2->prev;
        }
        else  {
            list3 = init(tail1->field,first3);
            tail1 = tail1->prev;
        }
        while (tail1 != NULL||tail2 != NULL) {
            while (tail1 != NULL) {
                if ((tail1->field) >= (tail2->field)) {
                    list3->next = tail1;
                    list3 = list3->next;
                    list3->next = NULL;
                    tail1 = tail1->prev;
                }
                else break;
            }
            if (tail1 == NULL) {
                while (tail2 != NULL) {
                    list3->next =tail2;
                    list3 = list3->next;
                    list3->next = NULL;
                    tail2 = tail2->prev;
                }
            }
            while (tail2 != NULL) {
                if ((tail2->field) >= (tail1->field)) {
                    list3->next=tail2;
                    list3 = list3->next;
                    list3->next = NULL;
                    tail2 = tail2->prev;
                }
                else break;
            }
            if (tail2 == NULL) {
                while (tail1 != NULL) {
                    list3->next = tail1;
                    list3 = list3->next;
                    list3->next = NULL;
                    tail1 = tail1->prev;
                }
            }
        }
        return list3;
    }

    void show(list *first) {
        list *temp = first;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->field << "\t";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void deleteList(list *delList) {
        list *temp;
        while (delList != NULL) {
            temp = delList;
            delList = delList->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на испорченный heap. Если это windows, расставьте по тексту эту строчку в разные места:

```
assert(_heapchk() == _HEAPOK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам мое решение задания:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename TYPE_ELEM>
class ListElem {
public:
  ListElem<TYPE_ELEM>* prev;
  TYPE_ELEM elem;
  ListElem<TYPE_ELEM>* next;
  ListElem() {
    this->prev = nullptr;
    this->next = nullptr;
  }
  ListElem(ListElem* prev, TYPE_ELEM elem) {
    this->prev = prev;
    this->elem = elem;
    this->next = nullptr;
  }
};


template <typename TYPE_ELEM>
class LinkedList{
private:
  int length;
  ListElem<TYPE_ELEM>* head;
  void init() {
    this->length = 0;
    this->head = new ListElem<TYPE_ELEM>();
    this->head->prev = this->head;
  }
public:
  explicit LinkedList() {
    this->init();
  }

  LinkedList(LinkedList&& l) {
    this->init();
    this->extend(l);
  }

  int get_length() {
    return this->length;
  }

  void append(const TYPE_ELEM elem) {
    this->length += 1;
    auto list_elem = new ListElem<TYPE_ELEM>(this->head->prev, elem);
    this->head->prev->next = list_elem;
    this->head->prev = list_elem;
  }

  void extend(const LinkedList& l) {
    auto elem = l.head->next;
    for(TYPE_ELEM i = 0;i < l.length ;i++) {
      this->append(elem->elem);
      elem = elem->next;
    }
  }

  LinkedList reversed() {
    LinkedList l;
    auto elem = this->head->prev;
    for(int i = 0;i < this->length ;i++) {
      l.append(elem->elem);
      elem = elem->prev;
    }
    return l;
  }

  void show() {
    auto elem = this->head->next;
    for(int i = 0;i < this->length ;i++) {
      std::cout << " " << elem->elem;
      elem = elem->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  void clear() {
    auto elem = this->head->prev;
    auto length = this->length;
    for(int i = 0;i < length;i++) {
      auto temp = elem;
      elem = elem->prev;
      delete temp;
      elem->next = nullptr;
      this->length -= 1;
    }
  }

  LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList&& l) {
    if (this != &l) { 
      this->clear();
      delete this->head;
      this->init();
      this->extend(l);
    }  
  }

  ~LinkedList() {
    this->clear();
    delete this->head;
  }
};


int main() {
  LinkedList<int> l1, l2, l3;
  l1.append(1);
  l1.append(2);
  l1.append(3);
  l1.append(4);
  std::cout << "L1: ";
  l1.show();
  l2.append(5);
  l2.append(6);
  l2.append(7);
  l2.append(8);
  std::cout << "L2: ";
  l2.show();
  l3.extend(l1);
  l3.extend(l2);
  std::cout << "L3: ";
  l3.show();
  std::cout << "L3 reversed: ";
  l3 = l3.reversed();
  l3.show();
  return 0;
}
```